# Microscopic leak from compression fitting on refrigerator line

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator

Looking to split the water supply behind my fridge and route to my coffee maker as pictured. All the other connections are watertight with no leakage whatsoever, however this one connection is dripping about 5 drops an hour. The leakage seems to be coming from the connector side and not the male splitter side.

I have tried tightening by hand, +1/2, and as tight as humanly possible still with residual weeping. Tried with/without Teflon tape. I have swapped out the hose as well, should I try a third hose or new splitter? Any putty that may help?

Thanks in advance for any assistance as I am a new DIY'er!

Hose: https://www.lowes.com/pd/EASTMAN-10-ft-L-1-4-in-Compression-Inlet-x-1-4-in-Outlet-Stainless-Steel-Ice-Maker-Connector/3196995

Splitter: https://www.lowes.com/pd/B-K-1-4-in-Compression-Tee-Fitting/1000505441

[image: leak]

[image: set up]

Update:
New hose on the left, old on the right. New one looks intact to me.
[image: New hose on the left, old on the right. New one looks intact to me.]

Have now started to notice a small leak from the fridge side as well. Will try a new hose.
[image: Have now started to notice a small leak from the fridge side as well. Will try a new hose.]

---

Thank you so much for the response. The supply hose is brand new so it should not be distorted or missing a washer, but I will double check. Perhaps at this point I will start over with a new hose and new splitter and not overtighten. Yes I am using only the bare threaded male end of the splitter.

Edit: All is well after swapping out for a third hose, no Teflon, hand tightened + 1/2. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Is this after you split it or before?  The seal in these happens at the end, not at the threads.  There is normally a washer, which may be missing or damaged.

Comment: Sometimes even brand new supply hoses have defects - they are often made for price over quality.  Looking at the condition of the washer on your old hose, I would definitely replace any similar-era hoses you find. Those washers and the internal plastic hose inside the metal braiding decays over time just as with washing machine supply hoses and you don't want a flood!

Answer (score 2):

As Rohit noted, with those braided supply hoses, the connection is an end seal of the black rubber washer inside the hose end onto the smooth brass rim of the threaded end of the splitter.

1. Remove all traces of/don't use any teflon tape, pipe dope, or putty - they just interfere.
2. As you reported, tighten finger tight, then use a wrench to add an extra half turn. Any tighter and the rubber washer can be distorted/damaged.
3. Since you have already tried a different hose, there may be a defect on the brass rim of the splitter (depression/gouge/divot) preventing the rubber washer from sealing properly. Replacing the splitter would solve this problem.
4. Make sure you have discarded all the nuts, ferrules and inserts that came with the splitter and are using only the bare threaded core:

[image]